# Add UIGestureRecognizer with UIScrollView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have ScrollView on my screen and also have two sliders on the scroll view.The problem is that my scrollview is recognizing gesture properly but slider gives me gesture trouble while moving.

So to detect the gestures of slider
I have tried following `gestureRecognizer` method but still it is not working:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:         (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (touch.view != yourScrollView) { 
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: now it starts detecting slider gesture but slider is not moving smoothly

Comment: Set constraints correctly for both scrollview and slider.try to put slider in contentView(UIView). also set contentsize scrollview property hope this work.